# Ardor / NXT node stuck on ** Broadcasting blockchain state change from UP_TO_DATE to DOWNLOADING **

Tags: nodes, nxt, ardor

My node has just stopped syncing and it just displays:

**Broadcasting blockchain state change from UP_TO_DATE to DOWNLOADING**

How can one fix this?